# Git stash not responding

Tags: git, wsl-2

I attempted to stash untracked files in a git repo, that contains a submodule. But the command is getting stuck:
[image]

It turned out that it might happen due to Zone.Identifier files, that got there from win env.

Comment: Try adding all the files, except the submodule, and then running `git stash` without `-u`?

Comment: which git version you are using?

Comment: the `wsl-2` tag implies you are running your commands on Windows, correct ? (the operations done by git withe the file system are known to be slower on Windows)

Comment: not sure if related - but to my knowledge `:` in Filename is problematic in NTFS or FAT file names.